# Copy Layouts-o-Rama configuration from VS2012 to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

How do I copy my [Layouts-o-Rama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c) configuration to VS2013 now that I have upgraded?

Layouts-o-Rama is a brilliant Visual Studio extension when you find yourself using VS in different locations with different monitor setups.  Just save a layout for each location/personality and create hot keys to toggle them.

It is good at what it does, but I just installed VS 2013 and I find that Layouts-o-Rama doesn't have the presets from VS2012.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 now supports window layout management out of the box, and the settings synchronize along with your Microsoft account: http://www.alexdresko.com/2014/11/14/window-layout-management-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: I've found this extension perfect for when VS occasionally and mysteriously resets my layout, even on the same machine...

Answer (score 11):

It is possible. But it involves a few manual steps:

1. Install the plugin from the gallery in VS 2013
2. Copy over your settings:

   > c:\Users{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\SettingsORama\

   to

   > c:\Users{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\SettingsORama\
3. Edit all of your settings files (for eg. `"C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\SettingsORama\2 monitors.vssettings"`) and change the `ApplicationIdentity` to `12.0` for VS 2013

   ```
   <UserSettings> 
       <ApplicationIdentity version="12.0" />
   ```